# ios: pinchGesture that only happen once

Tags: ios, ipad, gesture, pinch

In IOS 6, how to add PinchGesture that only detect once?

I have a UIView that I add to pinchGesture:

```
[self addPinchGestureRecognizersToView:self.view];
```

Then I attach a function to this Pinch to call out a uiview. The problem is when I pinch, the event occur a few times, that make the ViewController to addSubview many times depend on how many times the event occur.

So how can I actually limit it to just 1 time or remove it at the moment it detect a pinch. I tried:

```
[self.view removeGestureRecognizer:UIPinchGestureRecognizer];
```

But I got an compile error.

Comment: why can't you just keep a count on how many times does the event calls?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the suggestions. I just thought of the simplest solution - Add a BOOLEAN to check. The rest work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You should know pinch gesture is a continuous gesture. That is to say it can be recognized many time during the touch procedure.

If you want to recognize only once, you can remove it the first time it recognizes. The reason you get a compile error is you should 'remember' your gesture and remove it later.

Answer (score 0):

`[self.view removeGestureRecognizer:UIPinchGestureRecognizer];`

This method call is invalid. `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` is a class not an instance. You have to replace it with the correct recognizer you have added.

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer* recognizer in [self.view.gestureRecognizers copy]) {
   if ([recognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPinchGestureRecognizer class]]) {
       [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
   }
}
```